# Consistent Results for MatrixExp, DSolve and Eigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I have the system

$$Y' = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 4 \\ -8 & 4 \end{pmatrix}Y$$
Using [*DSolve*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
   DSolve[{x'[t] == -4x[t]+4 y[t], y'[t] == -8x[t] + 4y[t]},{x,y},t]
```

Produces

$$x = c_2 \sin (4 t)+c_1 (\cos (4 t)-\sin (4 t)) \\y = c_2 (\sin (4 t)+\cos (4 t))-2 c_1 \sin (4 t)$$

Finding the Fundamental Matrix, $e^{A t}$, using [*MatrixExp*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html) as

```
   MatrixExp[{{-4t,4t},{-8t,4t}}]
```

Produces

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (4 t)-\sin (4 t) & \sin (4 t) \\
 -2 \sin (4 t) & \sin (4 t)+\cos (4 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice how that perfectly aligns with the DSolve result.

If I use Eigensystem

```
    Eigensystem[{{-4, 4}, {-8, 4}}]
```

This produces

$$ \lambda_i = \pm 4i, v_1 = (1 \pm i, 2) $$

That is a correct result, but I am wondering if we can coax the eigenvectors to be a in a form that can produce the previous two results from the imaginary to real conversion using Euler's Formula.

$$e^{4 i t} = (\cos 4 t + i \sin 4t)\begin{pmatrix} 1 - i \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a way to peer in to how Mathematica calculated the previous results and make the eigenvectors (since they are not unique) be in a form that I can use this expansion to generate either of the previous two forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Idea is, that you have to introduce constants `A, B` for every individual term too.
You'll then recognize the solution to be obtainable, if you set `A=Conjugate[B]`. Afterwards its just getting the right expression for the constants to match the exact same solution as the one from above.

As is shown in this example:

```
(
(A + B*I)*Exp[4 I*t]*{1 - I, 2} +
(A - B*I)*Exp[-4 I*t]*{1 + I, 2}
) /. {A -> C[2]/4, B -> C[1]/2 - C[2]/4} // ExpToTrig // Simplify
```

> {C[1] Cos[4 t] + (-C[1] + C[2]) Sin[4 t],
> C[2] Cos[4 t] + (-2 C[1] + C[2]) Sin[4 t]}

Comment: Interesting. Is there some way to automate finding $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Well, I found it by solving the resulting expression with the DSolve result for A and B. To automated that might be hard since there is no real target to optimize it to.